# Gitlab CICD Tags pipeline duplication

Tags: gitlab, yaml, continuous-integration, tags, gitlab-ci

i have gitlab-ci.yml file with simple workflow like

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event"
```

There is job that automate code analisys and it also have simple rule

```yaml
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "main"
```

When i create tag it trigger code_analisys job and i want to prevent that. Tried with:

```yaml
- if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG == null
```

But the problem is still occuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to trigger the pipeline when pushing a tag, use the following rule:

```yaml
rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    when: never
```